# Xcode 9 classes not showing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

When i opened the **XCode 9**, I can not see my classes. Like Below image;

[image]

**My controllers :**

[image]

What is the problem? 
Anyone know?

Comment: in the project folder you are seen or not?

Comment: you are selected **Show only Recent files** in **Navigation Area**, dont worry your files are not missing

Comment: How can i change ?

Comment: Tap the clock icon at bottom to toggle recent files mode on and off

Comment: @Daniel please type answer this is fixed my problems.

Comment: @ThreeCoins deserves the answer credit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if anything selected in this area unselect  once and check in Xcode

[image]